# Component dissapears after routing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My router.js

```
 const routes = [{
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
    children: [{
      path: "/channels/:id/messages",
      name: "ChannelPaths",
      component: Content,
    }]
  },
```

Home.vue

```
.d-flex  
  Sidebar
  Content
  Sideright
```

My site looks like this

Menu items | Content

Whenever I click on one of the menu items, the params url switch to different but the content wont update. I need to press f5 to see it.

Comment: how is your app structured? where your Menu lives?

Comment: I have home.vue component where I keep all the 3 components, menu, content,right-content. I've updated my post

Comment: ok, and your "ChannelPaths" is the child of "Home" in your `router.js`?

Comment: When I make it as a child, then it doesn't work properly. Messages in current channel won't switch at all.

Comment: in this case by navigating to "ChannelPaths" you are replacing the Home component and Menu disappears. You have to use <router-view>Content</router-view>

Comment: I mean when I switch view it forces me to press f5 to content appear, when I make it as children.

Comment: a fiddle would be useful to look at your problem. But yes, you have to put  "ChannelPaths" as child, or put your Menu to Content component, but this is not the way you want to go